# Just installed openSUSE 11.3, and after 5 seconds , my keyboard goes to sleep for 1-2 characters?

Tags: opensuse, keyboard

My keyboard skips one or two characters, whenever I stop typing for 5 seconds or more. Since I just installed 11.3 openSUSE, I don't know if this issue is an improper configuration, a bug in 11.3, or my keyboard failing. It doesn't matter what application I am running, or what keys are pressed.

Keyboard failure doesn't seem likely. I cannot find anything in either yast or personal preferences that might fix it. Thus, I suspect something in SUSE, maybe the keyboard driver.

It is very annoying, having to **k**key first characters twice after pausing.

Comment: @Edwin KDE, or Gnome? and does it affect a non windowed environment (e.g. a virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>)? also any chance you've tried another distro's livecd (failing hardware should fail in that env too)?

Comment: KDE and doesn't affect non-windowed.

Comment: I reinstalled SUSE and the problem stopped, but after applying all updates, the problem has returned.

Comment: I don't know if the following notification is relevant, or another issue, but I get the following notification: "Nepomuk was not able to find the configured database 'redland.' Existing data thus cannot be accessed.

Comment: I found the Nepomuk message in the openSUSE support database, and corrected it. Now the missing character after delay is fixed, too.

Comment: Please close this post.

Comment: @Edwin instead of closing you could post how you fixed it as an answer so other people can find the solution.

Comment: Similar error for me. Keyboard shortcuts would not work for some reason. I am disabling Desktop effects now and I will test.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your kernel? There was an update last week that introduced this error: http://lwn.net/Articles/404712/ It should be fixed sometime soon.

In the meantime you can downgrade to 2.6.34-12.3